# Google Dataproc jobs tab not listing the jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I have created dataproc cluster and processed dataproc jobs. When I select jobs tab, It didn't list the created jobs even when I select all regions.

Answer (score 0):

There was a recently identified bug where jobs fail to list if you have no jobs in the older "global"region; this is fixed in code but the fix will take some time to get released everywhere, possibly up to middle of next week or so.

In the meantime, if you run any job in the "global" region and don't delete it, you should be able to see all of your jobs in other regions as well.

Once the fix is rolled out, this workaround will no longer be necessary.